# Values from one column common to values in another column

Tags: sql

I have a table where I'm concerned with two columns, namely orderNumber and productCode.
The table is configured as such

```
orderNumber    productCode
1000                a
1000                b
1000                c
1001                a
1001                f     
1001                d     ...
```

I need to find the productCode common to all orders. How do I go about this task?

Answer (score 1):

One way ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e71c0/1))

```
SELECT productCode
FROM   OrderProducts
GROUP  BY productCode
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT orderNumber) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT orderNumber)
                                      FROM   OrderProducts)
```

If `orderNumber,productCode` is guaranteed unique and you have a separate table with all orders then

```
SELECT productCode
FROM   OrderProducts
GROUP  BY productCode
HAVING COUNT(orderNumber) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Orders)
```

would be better.

See [Divided We Stand: The SQL of Relational Division](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/) for some alternate methods.

Comment: Thank you! 
Could you suggest learning material or share a link for spatial queries? I'm struggling with the syntax for mysql server 5.5.